# Extract text in table cell before input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML of the form:-

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text for input 1<br/><div>Lots of textual data</div><input id="field1" class="mandatory"/></td>
    <td>Text for input 2<br/><input id="field2" class="mandatory"/></td?
    <td>Text for input 3<br/><input id="field3"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(but with many more fields & rows).

I'm iterating through the mandatory class and, where the input field is empty, I want to display the text preceding the `<br/>` but not anything else.

Using:-

```
$(this).parent().text();
```

only works up to a point because it also displays the text in the `<div>`

Is there a way that I can limit the text to just that before the `<br/>`?

Comment: Wrap that text in a `span` or `label` and target that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```
$(this).parent().contents().eq(0).text();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T9CC2/)

Comment: This is how you retrieve non-wrapped text. The text-block will show up as its own node after using `.contents()`.

Comment: Oh, I've just found it!  It picks out the first element (ie the text up to the <br/>) only. Tks

Answer (score 0):

You may update your HTML markup to keep your message in a span tag with a special css class which you can use to make your jQuery selection more easier.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="msg">Text for input 1</span><br/>
        <div>Lots of textual data</div><input id="field1" class="mandatory"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and now use the `closest` method to get the parent td and use the `find` method to get the span

```
$(".mandatory").each(function(index,item){

     var msg=$(this).closest("td").find("span.msg").html();
     //do something with msg now 
});
```

Here is a working sample http://jsbin.com/oDUPujOl/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can `clone` your target `TD` and `remove` the `elements` which are with unnecessary text. Now you easily fetch the `required text` from that `TD`. For reference please read this : [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Try this one,

```
$("#field1").keyup(function(){
    var xClone = $(this).parent().clone();
    xClone.find('div').remove();
    alert((xClone).text());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cWFM8/2/)

Comment: Way to break the stackoverflow css with your long name. Some guy is really angry right now. :o

Answer (score 0):

Time for some plain JS, as jQuery doesn't really play well with textnodes:

```
var text = this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeValue.trim();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T9CC2/2/)